# Linearly independent set for sin and cos

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, matrix-equations

Prove that $ \{1,\sin(x),\cos(x),\sin(2x),\cos(2x),\sin(3x),\cos(3x),...\}$ is linearly independent in $C^{\infty}(R)$.

I know how to show the set $ \{ \sin(x),\cos(x),\sin(2x),\cos(2x)\}$ is linearly independent:

Let $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $x\mapsto a\sin x + b\cos x+ c\sin 2x + d\cos 2x$ is the $0$ function. For $x=0$, we get $b+d=0$. For $x=\pi$, $-b+d=0$. Combining the two, $b=d=0$. Similarly we can show $a=c=0$.

I do not think i can use the same approach here and is $C^{\infty}(R)$ just the infinite dim vector space of complex numbers? Is there a different approach that can show all coefficients are 0 in this infinite set?

Comment: Are you allowed to use the "Fourier series of $0$" ?

Comment: i do not think so sorry

Comment: This equivalent to the linear independence of the functions $e^{ikt}$, which are the powers of $e^{it}$.

Comment: oh i think i know what you mean, like the generating function? if so, would you care to explain a bit more in details?

Comment: This is equivalent to the orthogonality of Fourier basis functions $\{1, \sin(x), \cos(x), \sin(2x), \cos(2x), \ldots\}$.

Comment: I think taking the Fourier transform of both sides of the equation
$$0=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left[a_n\cos(nx)+b_n\sin(nx)\right]$$
might produce nice results

Answer (score 1):

By definition of linear independence (of an infinite set of vectors), we need to show for any positive integer $m, n$, $0 < i_1 < \cdots < i_m, 0 \leq j_1 < \cdots < j_n$, the set $S:= \{\sin(i_1x), \ldots, \sin(i_mx), \cos(j_1x), \ldots, 
\cos(j_nx)\}$ is linearly independent. To this end, assume
\begin{align*}
a_1\sin(i_1x) + \cdots + a_m\sin(i_mx) + b_1\cos(j_1x) + \cdots + b_n\cos(j_nx) = 0,
\tag{1}
\end{align*}
where $a_1, \ldots, a_m, b_1, \ldots, b_n \in \mathbb{R}$.

Multiplying on both sides of $(1)$ with $\sin(i_kx), 1 \leq k \leq m$ and then integrating both sides of $(1)$ from $0$ to $2\pi$ yields $a_k = 0$, where we used the orthogonality of Fourier functions:
\begin{align*}
& \int_0^{2\pi} \sin(Mx)\cos(Nx)dx = 0; \\
& \int_0^{2\pi} \sin(Mx)\sin(Nx)dx = \begin{cases}
0 & M \neq N, \\
\pi & M = N,
\end{cases} \\
\end{align*}
for non-negative integers $M$ and $N$. Similarly, you can deduce $b_1 = \cdots = b_n = 0$. Therefore $a_1 = \cdots = a_m = b_1 = \cdots = b_n = 0$. That is, $S$ is
linearly independent.

Comment: thank you so much, this is an elegant solution but i was wondering if there are more basic ways that does not use fourier basis?

Comment: In fact, "Fourier basis" is just for a reference convenience, the key idea is to apply the integral identity in the answer to show that all coefficients are $0$. That said, alternatively, you may consider taking derivatives on both sides of $(1)$ to form a linear system, then try to argue that this linear system only has zero solution. This also solves the problem quite cleverly, but with substantially more writings.

Comment: thank you got it; and what about the leading 1 in the set?

Comment: @jamesblack $1$ is covered by $0 \leq j_1$, that is, $j_1$ can take $0$ so you can get $1$ covered.

Answer (score 1):

An approach that does not involve Fourier series or integration:

Suppose that the given set is linearly dependent, that is, there is some non-trivial sum $$\sum_{k=0}^na_k\cos kx+b_k\sin kx=0$$

At $x=0$, $$\sum_{k=0}^na_k=0$$

Differentiate the identity twice to get $\sum_{k=0}^n-a_kk^2\cos kx-b_kk^2\sin kx=0$, from which we obtain again (at $x=0$), $$\sum_{k=0}^nk^2a_k=0$$

Repeat this for $2m$ derivatives up to $m=n$: $$\sum_{k=0}^nk^{2m}a_k=0$$

Hence writing these as a matrix, $$\begin{pmatrix}1&1&\cdots&1\\1&2^2&\cdots&n^2\\\vdots\\1&2^{2n}&\cdots&n^{2n}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a_0\\ a_1\\\vdots\\ a_n\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\\vdots\\0\end{pmatrix}$$
Now it can be checked that the determinant of the matrix is non-zero (Vandermonde matrix), so $(a_0,\ldots,a_n)=(0,\ldots,0)$.
Repeat for $b_k$ using $x=\pi/2$.

---

There are other similar approaches. The closest to the asker's method is to write the identity as $\sum_kc_ke^{ikx}=0$ and evaluate at $x=m\pi/n$, $m=0,\ldots,n-1$, to get $\sum_kc_k=0$, $\sum_kc_k\omega^k=0$, etc.